# Trying to minimize the flags of each USA State to 16 by 11 pixels in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to minimize the flags of each USA State to 16 by 11 pixels in Photoshop.

When using "free transform", I get a very ugly result for some flags such as the flag of the State of Alaska.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that there's much you can do here. I think the easiest thing to do is recreate it by hand.

Comment: @Johannes  I think the issue is that the .png file I'm trying to paste the flag to has a compression setting which makes the small flag blurry. Is there a way to have a .png file with absolutely no compression?

Comment: It's anti-aliasing when you reduce something that small. As @Johannes points out. the only real way to do this to redraw it pixel by pixel.

Comment: @Scott I redrew it pixel by pixel in a separate file, then I tried to copy and paste it into the .png, it instantly became blurry even if both file have the same pixel resolution.

Comment: I wish there was a way to upload my .psd and my .png files here

Comment: @Scott  Just created a new question here for this issue: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/87050/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-png-file-with-absolutely-no-compression

Comment: [Already done..... in some respect](https://www.google.com/search?q=us+state+flags&espv=2&biw=1222&bih=1228&tbs=isz:ex,iszw:16,iszh:11&tbm=isch&source=lnt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the options on the bottom of the Image Size dialog.
You can try that options to see which gives the best result.
-Bicubic Automatic
-Bilinear
-Bicubic
-Bicubic Smoother
-Bicubic Sharper
-Bicubic Automatic
For Usa and Brasil flag, Bilinear worked very good for me.
But it should'n not be forgotten that; a 16x11 image will not include stars since there is not enough pixels to achieve this. It will be a graphic presentation of the flag that has most characteristics of original ..

If i were you , i was going to write an action and save them with all these options processed and look to see, which gives best results and I will pick them.

Here is what i made with Bilinear option. It seems good.

[image]

Another way is drawing your own.

Comment: Any of the "image size" options will work with the Alaska Flag :/

Answer (score 0):

16x11 is far too less to represent real objects such as flags. If you reduce an image to 16x11, Photoshop (or equivalent) surely does its best. Its the best in the way that you have told you want it. You have told what you want by choosing the resizing algorithm.

Unfortunately all forms that do not fit into 16x11 grid will be either - depending on the used algorithm - ragged to formless or blurred by averaging (in math it's antialiasing). The latter is the way to keep the average form right.

The only solution is to distort the proportions in the image to ones that well enough fit in 16x11. In practice you must draw your own. The key is to create the right impression, not to be accurate. Achieved sharpness well compensates the distortion.

The following is an example, how heavy distortion I mean:

[image]

Comment: Very nice hand design!

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys! I found the best way to do what I want to do!

1-Get free .ai files of the flags.
2-Open each of the files with Photoshop and set the size to (16 by 11 pixels).
3-Save each file .png 
4-Merge them with Aseprite (Photoshop won't do it without distorting the pixels and Microsoft Paint won't keep the transparency)

It's the only way to get this very nice result for the Alaska Flag:
[image]

Thanks all for the help!

EDIT: Some flags gave better results with the options on the bottom of the Image Size dialog.